# Number of switches

Tags: switch

I was wondering how would you determine the right number of switches on a network. How would you calculate the delays in the switch.

Comment: Perhaps you can explain what you mean by the "right" number?

Comment: Aren't all the cool sysadmins using left-handed switches these days?

Comment: Check out this other (closed) question: http://serverfault.com/q/318626/9278

Answer (score 3):

As few as possible for the architecture you're designing.